# An android app using AutoCompleteTextView gives warning and doesn't get run on emulator

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to make a little app to learn the AutoCompleteTextView class. Below is the code I wrote :

The MainActivity.java file :

package com.infinityfraction.autocompletetextviewlistview;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // set the contents which will act as the options for the user.
    String town[] = {"Kalyani Nagar","Kothrud","Aundh","Viman Nagar","Balewadi","Swargate","Yerawada","Katraj","Kasba Peth","Bhosari","Chinchwad","Hadapsar","Warje","Vadgaon Budruk","Shivajinagar","Lohegaon","Akurdi","Ala","Alandi Devachi","Alandi Khed","Alandi Road","Ambegaon BK","Anandnagar","Ane","Aundh Road","Balaji Nagar","Baner","Baner Road","Belha","Bhandarkar Road","Bhavani Peth","Bhawani Peth Road","Bhor","Bhosari","Bibvewadi","Bopodi","Budhwar Peth","Bund Garden Road","Camp","Chakan","Chikhali","Chinchwad East","Chinchwadgaon","Dapodi","Dattawadi","Daund","Deccan Gymkhana","Dehu Road","Dhankawadi","Dhayari","Dhole Patil Road","Erandwana","Fatima Nagar","Fergusson College Road","Ganesh Peth","Ganeshkhind","Ghorpade Peth","Ghorpuri","Gokhale Nagar","Gultekdi","Guruwar Peth","Hadapsar","Hadapsar Indl Estate","Haveli","Hingane Khurd","Hingne Khurd","Hinjewadi","Indrayani Darshan Dehu Road","Jangali Maharaj Road","Junnar","Kalewadi","Kalyani Nagar","Karve Nagar","Karve Road","Kasarwadi","Khadaki","Khadki","Kharadi","Khed","Kondhwa","Kondhwa Budruk","Kondhwa Khurd","Koregaon Park","Koregaon Park Road 1","Law College Road","Laxmi Road","Lonavala","Loni Kalbhor","Lulla Nagar","Mahatma Gandhi Road","Mangalwar Peth","Manik Baug","Market Yard","Model Colony","Mukund Nagar","Mundhawa","Nagar Road","Nana Peth","Narayan Peth","Narayangaon","Navi Peth","Nigdi","Padmavati","Parvati","Pashan","Paud Road","Phursungi","Pimpri","Pirangut","Prabhat Road","Pune Railway Station","Rasta Peth","Raviwar Peth","Sadashiv Peth","Sahakar Nagar","Salunke Vihar","Sanghavi","Sasoon Road","Satara Road","Senapati Bapat Marg","Shaniwar Peth","Shivaji Nagar","Shukrawar Peth","Sinhagad","Sinhagad Road","Somwar Peth","Talegaon Dabhade","Thergaon","Tilak Road","Uruli","Vadgaon Sheri","Vishrantwadi","Wagholi","Wakad","Wakadewadi","Wanowarie","Wanowri","Wanworie","Armament","Bhosarigaon","Dighi Camp","Ex Servicemen Colony","I.A.T. Pune","Khadakwasla","Mundhwa","Navsahyadri","Pimpri Colony","Pimpri Chinchwad","Pune City","Pune","Range Hill","Shivaji Housing Society","S.P. College","Secondary School Certificate","Wadgaon Budruk","Wanawadi","Warje Malwadi","spacer"};

    // Create the object of AutoCompleteTextView;
    AutoCompleteTextView actv;

    void initialize()
    {
        // this is the creation of the object of AutoCompleteTextView
        actv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,town);

        actv.addTextChangedListener((TextWatcher) MainActivity.this);
        actv.setAdapter(adapt);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
    }
}
```

The activity_main.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.infinityfraction.autocompletetextviewlistview.MainActivity">


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Your City"
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="The Possible Options Are : "
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

On opening this application on mobile this shows : Unfortunately, "The App" has stopped.

In the terminal I can see this message :

```
Warning: /home/aupadhyay/AndroidStudioProjects/AutoCompleteTextViewListView/app/src/main/nevercreated.xml:1:1-12:12 Warning:
    Missing 'package' declaration in manifest at nevercreated.xml:1:1-12:12
[16510099]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - The current <b>inotify</b>(7) watch limit is too low. <a href="https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit">More details.</a> 
Apr 15, 2016 2:32:05 PM com.android.tools.idea.monitor.network.NetworkSampler checkStatsFile
WARNING: IOException null in ls /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats
```

The AndroidMainfest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.infinityfraction.autocompletetextviewlistview">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your manifest please.

Comment: You should have some exception in the log.

Comment: @Nanoc : can you please explain it more?

Comment: That log you posted doesnt show any Exception, something must be causing the crash...

Answer (score 1):

App crash due to this line.

`actv.addTextChangedListener((TextWatcher) MainActivity.this);`

Change it to

```
actv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Comment: doing this doesn't crash the app. But also it doesn't actually implements AutoCompleteTextView Properly. i.e. it does not show any preferable options in drop down menu

Comment: for that you need to add Filter in your adapter. override getFilter();